# Running a class from within a jar using ant

Tags: java, ant

im trying to invoke a specific class from within a jar file but I'm gettign below exception -

```
Buildfile: C:\Projects\GranHermano\build.xml
SignJadFilesInDir:
    [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell
```

My jar file contains all required jars (in this case poi-3.6-20091214.jar) so above exception should not be thrown.

This is how I am invoking the class -

```
<target name="SignJadFilesInDir" description="Signs all jad files in a dir" > 
 <java classname="com.src.SignDeviceJadInDir">
     <classpath>
        <pathelement location="BuildUtils.jar"/>
      </classpath>
  <arg line="${jadFileDir}"/>
  <arg line="${devicesExcelDir}"/>
  <arg line="${wtkDir}"/>
  <arg line="${keyStoreDir}"/>
  <arg line="${keyStoreId}"/>
  <arg line="${keyStorePwd}"/>
 </java>
</target>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that your jar files contains `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with `Class-Path: ...` pointing to `poi-...j`? Try to add it as `pathelement` anyway.

Comment: No, my manifest file just contains the manifest version. Within the jar I have alib folder that contains the poi jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please open jar `BuildUtils.jar` to ensure it well contains the classes of poi (and not poi jar, as I'm not aware of JRE support for jar-in-a-jar out of the box) ?
If your `BuildUtils.jar` contains `poi-3.6-20091214.jar` and not its classes, your exception is quite normal.

Comment: It contains the jars and not classes, so I need to generate the jar with the classes and not its required jars ?

Comment: Or you can replace your BuidlUtils.jar by the list of your class path entries. Fortunatly, in ant, you can use classpath references (for more info, see ant's manual : http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)

Comment: <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
      <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </classpath>